# Ошибка onFailurejava.io.EOFException: End of input at line 1 column 1 path $ в post-запросе

Tags: android, retrofit2

Ошибка  onFailurejava.io.EOFException: End of input at line 1 column 1 path $ в post-запросе

```
JsonObject createdJson = new JsonObject();
                createdJson.addProperty("email", email);
                createdJson.addProperty("first_name", firstName);
                createdJson.addProperty("last_name", lastName);
                createdJson.addProperty("password", newPassword);

                requestInterface.registerUser(createdJson).enqueue(new Callback<RegistrationResponse>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<RegistrationResponse> call, Response<RegistrationResponse> response) {
                        Log.d("myLogs", "Responce " + response.headers());
                        Log.d("myLogs", "Body " + response);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<RegistrationResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                        Log.d("myLogs", "onFailure" + t);
                    }
                });
```

Запрос:

```
@Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
    @POST("/signup")
    Call<RegistrationResponse> registerUser(@Body JsonObject dataToSend);
```